# Cake PHP 3.0.*-dev error?

Tags: cakephp

```
[root@skadi:/var/www/mailinglist]$ composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.0.*-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.x-dev].
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/debug_kit 3.0.x-dev requires cakephp/cakephp 3.0.*-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for cakephp/debug_kit 3.0.*-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/debug_kit[3.0.x-dev].
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

on Ubuntu 13.10 and later there is a problem for migration of php modules configuration from `/etc/php5/conf.d to /etc/php5/mods-available`

If you don't solve verify the `mcrypt` library

```
updatedb
locate mcrypt.so
locate mcrypt.ini
```

Comment: Thanks Luigi, the library was installed but I hadn't run sudo php5enmod mcrypt as I've never had to before, and it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 19):

Just for the record, as I didn't find a solution anywhere for **Arch Linux**: If you happen to use composer from the extra repository (*extra/php-composer*), it's actually not enough to enable the mcrypt extension in */etc/php/php.ini* because the global composer script uses its own ini-file (*/usr/share/php-composer/php.ini*).

To fix the mcrypt error, you can either:

- Enable mcrypt extension globally and run composer using `php /usr/bin/composer`.
- Add mcrypt extension to */usr/share/php-composer/php.ini* and prevent pacman from overwriting your changes by adding `NoUpgrade   = usr/share/php-composer/php.ini` to */etc/pacman/pacman.conf*.

Comment: Executing `php /usr/bin/composer` gives me `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phar' not found in /usr/bin/composer on line 23` error. The second solution seems to work. Any ideas on what's going wrong with the first one?

Comment: check if the phar extension is enabled globally: `$ grep phar /etc/php/php.ini` => `extension=phar.so`

Comment: Yeah, `phar` was disabled. I had checked that earlier myself and missed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I tried to install laravel with composer on my MAC Yosemite.
This was the error message I got from the terminal:

> laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP
>   extension mcrypt is missing from your system.

I followed these instructions to install mcrypt on my MAC:
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-development-server/
And that fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

Composer was blocking my install of cakephp because of a dependency on mcrypt, despite the fact that mcrypt was installed and working in my php configuration.

I finally realized that Composer was checking the cli mode of php, and I resolved the dependency by simply copying mcrypt.ini from /etc/php5/conf.d to /etc/php5/cli/conf.d.